# GeoServer Docker - Data loss

Tags: geoserver, mongodb, docker

I deployed a GeoServer image on Docker and I'm encountering a problem whenever the pod restarts. Every time the pod restarts, the workspace and datastore get deleted although the data in the database still there. I'm using MongoDB as database. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome! This seems more like a docker setup problem than a gis problem and may be more relevant for some other SE sites. YOu may have to look into persistent storage with docker

Comment: We've created a persistent volume for it so I don't know what went wrong. Could it be something with geoserver if the volume exists ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are storing your GeoServer data directory on the docker instance where the disk is not persisted over restarts.

Comment: I thought so at first but the developer that deployed it told me that he created a persistent volume for it. I don't know maybe there's something wrong with our configurations.

Comment: I want to make sure that the persistent volume is the only problem and it's nothing related to the geoserver in order to know where to check

Comment: log on the server and check - or look in the log file to see where it thinks the data dir is

Comment: There are no other well known causes for data loss. GeoServer is deployed in Docker routinely, the common cause of data loss is that the data-dir is not really external to the image (path mismatch, other misconfiguration being possible causes).